# Magento 1 : How to add custom filter in list page like price or name?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I'm building the frontend of the category page, among the filters that I have to create custom filter. I have no problem taking the data and having it available in the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` class, I can not change the query to apply the filter correctly.

I have full access to the collection, but I would like to know how to modify it in an "allowed" way

[image]